# Get COUNT of hours on 30 mins Interval

Tags: postgresql

I have this below data.

```
Date    Interval
2014-01-01  12:00 AM
2014-01-01  12:30 AM
2014-01-01  1:00 AM
2014-01-01  1:30 AM
2014-01-01  2:00 AM
2014-01-01  2:30 AM
2014-01-01  3:00 AM
2014-01-01  3:30 AM
2014-01-01  4:00 AM
2014-01-01  4:30 AM
```

I need to extract the hour of the interval column.

I could do it using `EXTRACT('hour', Interval)` which gives me the hour numbers as `int`.

Result will be as follows:

```
Date    Interval    HourCount
2014-01-01  12:00 AM    0
2014-01-01  12:30 AM    0
2014-01-01  1:00 AM 1
2014-01-01  1:30 AM 1
2014-01-01  2:00 AM 2
2014-01-01  2:30 AM 2
2014-01-01  3:00 AM 3
2014-01-01  3:30 AM 3
2014-01-01  4:00 AM 4
2014-01-01  4:30 AM 4
```

But what I'm looking for is. I need the count for every 30 mins as 1.

Example data what I'm looking for.

```
Date    Interval    HourCount
2014-01-01  12:00 AM    1
2014-01-01  12:30 AM    2
2014-01-01  1:00 AM 3
2014-01-01  1:30 AM 4
2014-01-01  2:00 AM 5
2014-01-01  2:30 AM 6
2014-01-01  3:00 AM 7
2014-01-01  3:30 AM 8
2014-01-01  4:00 AM 9
2014-01-01  4:30 AM 10
```

This way, in a day I'll be getting 48 intervals.

I could use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Date)`. But this will give me wrong count if any interval is been missed out.

Suppose if the below row is missed out.

```
2014-01-01  4:00 AM 9
```

I'll be getting `9` as the HourCount for this row.

```
2014-01-01  4:30 AM 9
```

Someone help me to get the count of hours on 30 mins interval.

Comment: Have you tried `generate_series()` with `interval '30 minutes'`?

Comment: I didn't know that there was function like that. I'll google now and try it.

Comment: It's generating me the time with certain intervals. But I need to count each 30 mins as 1. How can i do it?

Comment: Use `row_num()` over the generated intervals. They have no gaps so you will get the numbers you want.

Comment: I can use it. But if there's any interval missing. Then the `row_number()` will give me wrong value. I need them to be in chronological order. `0:00 as 1`, `0:30 as 2` and so on.

Comment: Also you can generate numbers 1..48 with `generate_series()` and get time intervals with `number * interval '30 minutes'`

Comment: If you generate intervals with `generate_series` there will be no missing intervals.

Comment: The interval are being taken a real data. I will not know whether there'll be any records for the particular interval.

Comment: You can generate intervals with `generate_series` first, to be sure that all intervals are present, use `row_number()` on generates intervals to get the number (all intervals will be present at this time) and then join generated interval numbers to the original table.

Comment: what datatype is the `interval` column? (which is not a good name for a column btw.)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
with series as 
(select interval_num, interval_num * interval '30 minutes' as interval_time
from generate_series(0,47) series(interval_num))

select *
from data_table
right join series on series.interval_time = data_table.interval
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you wrote, you can extract the hour, what you're missing is you can also extract the minutes and just check if they are bigger or equal 30.

```
SELECT date_part('hour', interval) * 2 + CASE WHEN date_part('minute', interval) >= 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```